# android mediacodec plays I-Frame only after receiving the next one (the time difference between I-Frames is 2-3 seconds)

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I'm trying to use the Android MediaCodec for decoding NAL units. The problem is that the video is played with a delay of 2-3 seconds, as the first I-Frame is played only after receiving the next one (the time difference between I-Frames is 2-3 seconds). So if I put the same I-frame 2 times in a row then it will play without any delay. But in this case I can't play the rest frames.

I do not understand what the problem could be. I have tried to fix it on my own, but I can't.

```
public void play(MediaCodec decoder, PESPacket currentPES){
    byte[] data = currentPES.data.toByteArray();
    pts = currentPES.getPts();

    try {
        if (data[4] == 0x67) {
            Log.d(TAG, "found sps/pps!");
            int ibs = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(0);
            if (ibs >= 0) {
                ByteBuffer buffer = decoder.getInputBuffers()[ibs];
                buffer.clear();
                buffer.put(data);
                decoder.queueInputBuffer(ibs, 0, data.length, pts, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG);
            }
        } else {
            if (data[4] == 0x41) {              // not I-frame
                int ibs = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(0);
                if (ibs >= 0) {
                    System.out.println("queueInputBuffer little");
                    ByteBuffer buffer = decoder.getInputBuffers()[ibs];
                    buffer.clear();
                    buffer.put(data);
                    decoder.queueInputBuffer(ibs, 0, data.length, pts, 0);
                }
            }
            if (data[4] == 0x65) {              // I-frame
                int ibs = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(0);
                if (ibs >= 0) {
                    System.out.println("queueInputBuffer");
                    ByteBuffer buffer = decoder.getInputBuffers()[ibs];
                    buffer.clear();
                    buffer.put(data);
                    decoder.queueInputBuffer(ibs, 0, data.length, pts, 0);
                }

            }
        }

        int outputBufferIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 10000);
        if (outputBufferIndex >= 0) {
            System.out.println("releaseOutputBuffer " + outputBufferIndex);
            decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, true);
        } else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
            System.out.println("INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED ");
        } else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
            MediaFormat format = decoder.getOutputFormat();
            System.out.println("INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED " + format);
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How big is your GOP? It's normal and expected for there to be some latency in the decoder -- you can't feed a single buffer in and wait for it to pop out the other side -- but it's usually on the order of 4 frames.

Comment: GOP size is 15. I have output buffer only after receiving fifteenth frame...
Is it normal behavior of MediaCodec?

Comment: I don't think there's a "normal" behavior. MediaCodec is a wrapper around the vendor-supplied codec driver, which uses the OMX interface. The amount of buffering depends on the codec implementation and the nature of the stream. I was seeing about 4 frames from initial startup when decoding AVC on a qcom-based device.

Comment: Thank you. So would you suggest what the problem could be? I'm testing on Nexus 5.

Comment: Did you ever solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is maybe too late, but wanted to share some info.

If only send IDR frames to video decoder, you can try set "android._num-input-buffers" and "android._num-output-buffers" to 1 in the MediaFormat when configure the decoder. This will try to allocate single buffer in video decoder, thus output buffer immediately.  However, the behaviour is not guaranteed, will depends on decoder's implementation.

I'm guessing, Google's software H264 decoder, "omx.google.h264.decoder" should support this behaviour, but I have not tested.

Refer to Android source code FrameDecoder.cpp as following for how to set the parameters. The FrameDecoder.cpp is the framework layer implementation of Android API MetaDataExtractor.getFrameAt().

http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/FrameDecoder.cpp#411

```
451    // For the thumbnail extraction case, try to allocate single buffer in both
452    // input and output ports, if seeking to a sync frame. NOTE: This request may
453    // fail if component requires more than that for decoding.
454    bool isSeekingClosest = (mSeekMode == MediaSource::ReadOptions::SEEK_CLOSEST)
455            || (mSeekMode == MediaSource::ReadOptions::SEEK_FRAME_INDEX);
456    if (!isSeekingClosest) {
457        videoFormat->setInt32("android._num-input-buffers", 1);
458        videoFormat->setInt32("android._num-output-buffers", 1);
459    }
```